# Inequality between operator norm and $\infty$-norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

For a matrix $A$, is there any relation between its [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) and $\infty$-norm (defined as the maximum of the absolute value of all the entries)?

Comment: In the same linked wiki page there are some relations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Examples_of_norm_equivalence).

Answer (score 2):

The fact:

> Any norms in a given finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent.

And it is easy to check the space of $n\times m$ matrices is a finite-dimensional vector space; also the operator norm and infinity norm are really norms.

So they are equivalent!
i.e.

$$||A||\le C_1||A||_{\infty}$$ and $$||A||_{\infty}\le C_2||A||$$

and that might be the relation you want.

Comment: So are there explicit relations? Like inequalities between the two norms. I think this might better help the OP.